# PHP making a table extracting data out of sql database using pdo

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a question about how I need to make a table with data from a database created in phpmyadmin using the pdo method. The connection to the database works and I got my data from a table in an array. But I need to make a table based on the data out of the table using a foreach loop.

```
<?php

include('connect.php');

try 
{
    $sql = 'select * from joke';

    $result = $pdo->query($sql);
}

catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $output = 'There is a problem: '.$e->getMessage();
    echo $output;
    exit();
}

$aOrders = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $aOrders[] = $row;
}


var_dump($aOrders);

echo '<table>';

foreach($aOrders as $key => $value)
{
    echo '<tr><td>'.$aOrders['id'].'</td><td>'.$aOrders['joketext'].'</td><td>'.$aOrders['jokeclou'].'</td><td>'.$aOrders['jokedate'].'</td></tr>';
};

echo '</table>';


?>
```

the 'id', 'joketext', 'jokeclou' and 'jokedate' are fields in my table and I want them to print it into a table.

Comment: What exactly is your question? If this isn't working, what's going wrong?

Comment: try changing `echo '<tr><td>'.$aOrders['id'].'</td><td>'.$aOrders['joketext'].'</td><td>'.$aOrders['jokeclou'].'</td><td>'.$aOrders['jokedate'].'</td></tr>';` **TO** `echo '<tr><td>'.$value['id'].'</td><td>'.$value['joketext'].'</td><td>'.$value['jokeclou'].'</td><td>'.$value['jokedate'].'</td></tr>';` as you are using `foreach($aOrders as $key => **$value**)`

Comment: I think he would like to make the number table column same to the data from database. He may have few/more columns in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `foreach()` you are trying to access the `$aOrders` array

```
echo '<tr><td>'.$aOrders['id'] ...
```

where you need to get the values in your `=> $values` of `foreach($aOrders as $key => $value)`

```
echo '<tr><td>'.$value['id'].'</td><td>'.$value['joketext'].'</td><td>'.$value['jokec‌​lou'].'</td><td>'.$value['jokedate'].'</td></tr>';
```